# What's the safest way to create an 'always logged in' IOS app?

Tags: ios, security, authentication

I'm writing code where the user signs up for an account with an e-mail+password. I would like to have login credentials stored in the IOS app, and then used for all remote actions the user makes (create order, update account info, etc.).

Is it safe to store the password in the IOS keychain using PDKeychainBindings and then send the user/pass over HTTPS for every request to the servers?

Is there a better/safer way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest way is not saving the password. Usually, when first connecting, you exchange the username & password for a permanent authorization token.

You then save this token into the keychain and all other server requests are authorized only by the token. You ask the user to enter password again only if the token becomes invalid.
(it's permanent, so it shouldn't expire but it can be invalidated by the server).

Comment: This is much better than saving the password in Keychain.

Comment: Sulthan, thanks for the response. Which part is unsafe? Storing the password in the keychain? Or sending the password over HTTPS for each action? For storing the token in the keychain, isn't that equal to storing the password? If someone got ahold of the token couldn't they use that as well? Is the only difference that the token is easily revokeable?

Comment: @BigCheesy Sending the password for every action is dangerous. You should always use some kind of token. Usually the tokens expire (1 hour or so). Mobile applications often use permanent tokens. It's easily revokable (user doesn't have to change password). And saving user password is never safe. Especially on devices that can be easily stolen.

Comment: THanks, Sulthan. I plan to go this route. On the server, upon registration, I will not store the password itself and will use whatever the best salted password hashing is. When a user logs in, they will send their password, and then get a token back to store. Does it matter how this token is generated? Can it just be some random token? And last question: I'm not completely sure that I could explain why a token is that much better to be sending back and forth than a password -- in either case, if the phone is stolen, the thief will be able to log in, right? Thanks so much!

Comment: @BigCheesy The password is something that must be always protected the most. It's the entry point for the communication. Sending something repeatedly makes it easier to hack. Using a token (even permanent token) you can ensure that the authorization data is significantly harder to hack from the communication (token is random, longer than most passwords). However there is also the reason of server performance. Checking the token against a table of current sessions is faster than hashing the password and comparing it with the user's hashed password in the DB.

Comment: Great explanation, makes tons of sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways:

1)You can use KeyChain: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Example:

```
//Initializing
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"YourAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];
//Saving
[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:kSecValueData];
[keychainItem setObject:@"username you are saving" forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
//Getting
NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecValueData];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount];
//deleting
[keychainItem resetKeychainItem];
```

2)You can use NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *pword = [prefs setObject:@"yourpassword" ForKey:@"password"];
NSString *username = [prefs setObject:@"username" ForKey:@"username"];
[prefs synchronize];
//getting 
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *pword = [prefs objectForKey:@"password"];
NSString *username = [prefs objectForKey:@"username"];
```

Method 1 is more secure than method 2. You can make method 2 more secure by encrypting your password and username.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Method 2 is not secure at all, `NSUserDefaults` are just a plist. Somebody steals your device, does a back up and has all the passwords in a nice xml file. Encryption is possible only if you can put the encryption key somewhere, so with encryption the method 2 would become method 1, only more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the response, lakesh. However, I wasn't asking for a keychain implementation. Rather, I was asking whether storing a password in the keychain is safe, And if it is safe to continually send the password over HTTPS for each action.